# Adding custom Item template to Visual studio 2015 solution explorer Context Menu

Tags: visual-studio-2015, contextmenu, visual-studio-templates

I can add a new Item through the context menu on folders in my solution explorer. Add -> New Item...

preferably I would like a new sub menu within the context menu for my own templates. If possible at all, I would like to pass parameters to the template so I can replace the placeholder parameters with user input.

Eventually I want the user (me) to think about the responsibility before creating a class and have that injected into the file as comments on creation.